# Sending user activation link via email. How it works?

Tags: php, post, get

After user registration, website send activation code to email. something like that. `www.domain.com/?activate=<code>`

I'm creating 2 variants of activation: 1.manual 2.auto
Lets say we have index.php.

1.**Manual method.** When someone wants to activate user manually all things are obvious:

User opens page www.domain.com/?activate

`Index.php` checks with following script and includes div file (which contains activation form)

```
   if (isset($_GET['activate'])) {
      $page='activate';
      $divfile = 'path to div.php';
    } 
    include $divfile;
```

Then page sends form data via ajax to `activation.php` file.

2.**Auto method**. Let's say user clicked directly to `www.domain.com/?activate=<code>`. What I want to do is, to check `if(!empty($_GET['activate']))`, if all right. I can't figure out what to do. Programmatically send something like POST to `activation.php` or what?

Comment: I've read through your question and I'm unsure what you want to achieve. What would be the purpose of the Auto method?

Comment: @zrvan he is just calling this way a simple activation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would call the required function from index.php. You wouldn't post anything.

Look at include and include_once.

You should encapsulate your activation code into a separate php file that acts as your function library. Create an activate() method that does the activation in a file called activate.php.

Then, from both activation.php and index.php, you do something like this:

```
include 'activate.php';

// Call the activate function from activate.php
activate($code);
```

However, you don't Post to call other code. You simply call it from PHP.

Comment: you mean include only in case auto activation?

Comment: @Tural, you would always include, but you would only call the activate() function on auto activate.

Comment: But i don't need to include in case manual activation, because page will send form data via Ajax to this file

Comment: @Tural, sorry for the mix up, you should move your activation function into its own file and call it from both activation.php and index.php. Sorry. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a POST is necessary if you are doing all of this on a single server. An include file with you activate function may be all you need. However, if you are communicating between servers, an HTTP_Request2 is the way to go, preferably with SSL options turned on.

It's pretty simple to do a GET with HTTP_Request2. Get the open source code for it from PEAR.

```
// prep $serverName by putting the get parameters at the end
// of the URL with ?this=that
$req = new HTTP_Request2($serverName, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$HTTPResponse = $req->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $_REQUEST in order to select both GET and POST (whichever is available). Then just use the same code which processes the form as the page which processes the ?activation=0000 request.

Comment: thx for info but please read question carefully. It's not what I need. you mean include this file in case auto activation and send via ajax in case manual activation?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu there is a problem with your question. I's INCREDIBLE UNCLEAR. Go figure.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is then. You seem to want to be able to process an activation code from a query string. This would normally be done with $_GET but if you want to use both post and get then you would use $_REQUEST.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your problem at all.

A usual activation schema is:

a link being sent to the user, pointing **directly to the activation script**, like this:

```
http://www.example.com/activation.php?code=code
```

in the activation.php you read the `$_GET['code']` variable and activate the user.

if you want to make user able to paste the code into some sort of form - add the form to this very page. they enter it and have the same link as a result. not a big deal.

that's all. No "programmatic POSTs", no ajax, no cunning schemes - everything PLAIN and SIMPLE.